# Replace var_dump with a custom function in PHP

Tags: php, debugging, var-dump

I wonder if it is possible to replace var_dump with some user defined function.
I know that you can use any kind of dumping functions of various modules, or some wrappers. 
But what I want to achieve is that anyone in my project who uses "var_dump", gets my new function, without "knowing" it and without the need to use a different syntax. 
Simply override the funcion.
Thanks

Comment: You need to edit the PHP source to achieve what you want. :-)

Comment: I do always write the function ```function vd($var) { echo '<pre>'; var_dump($var); echo '</pre>'; }```. I suggest you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't support re-declaring functions AFAIK. 
However there's a little trick you can do on a case specific basis.

Say you have this code in a file:

```
 var_dump($a);
 var_dump($b);
 var_dump($c);
```

You can just wrap this in a namespace like so:

```
namespace OverridingGlobalNamespace {
    function var_dump($_) {
          echo "My custom var_dump";
    }

   var_dump($a); //Will use namespace function instead of PHP function
   var_dump($b);
   var_dump($c); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to be an interesting solution, i have to check if this really works ;)

Comment: as you say - this is case specific, I still cannot apply it to all var_dump calls. So I guess it IS impossible :)

Comment: @Asped I don't claim this to be an ideal solution or even a good idea. I just find it to be an interesting quirk of the language. Ideally you'd want to not use var_dump but your own wrapper function which does what you want it to do (and which you can define differently on debug and production environments).

Comment: sure an own wrapper is the best solution. the only thing i intended to do was to ensure on a live project, that if there are some dumps which are done accidentaly or whatever, that they are suppressed, when used in a wrong way